# PHP short hash like URL-shortening websites

Tags: php, hash

I am looking for a PHP function that creates a short hash out of a string or a file, similar to those URL-shortening websites like [tinyurl.com](http://tinyurl.com)

The hash should not be longer than 8 characters.

Comment: I know this is an old question but check out: http://hashids.org/. Works with most programming languages

Comment: Check out [ShortCode](https://github.com/ajaxray/short-code) library. It does exactly what you want. Based on base conversion.

Comment: Other than using Adler-32 or CRC32, you can’t shorten modern (collision-resistant) hashes *that* much (i.e. down to 8 characters). Not with SHA-2, not with SHA-1, and not even with MD5. With [`Alphabet::convert($hash, Alphabet::HEX, Alphabet::ALPHANUMERIC)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-BaseConvert), you can get MD5 down to 22 (from 32) characters. What you want is instead encode the files’ integer IDs (e.g. from your database) with [`(new Id())->encode($id)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-IDs).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

URL shortening services rather use a auto incremented integer value (like a supplementary database ID) and encode that with [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) or other encodings to have more information per character (64 instead of just 10 like digits).

Comment: What this mean (more information per character) just curious!!

Comment: @ravisoni If you use the decimal digits `0`–`9` to represent a number, you have 10 possible values per encoded character (ld(10) ≈ 3.32 bits/character). However, if you represent the same number with Base64 characters, you have 64 possible values per encoded character (ld(64) = 6 bits/character). So with Base64 there is more information stored in each encoded character, i. e., 6 bits of information instead of 3.32 bits.

Comment: If you use base64, then nothing stops a script from saying for($i=0;$i<999999;$i++) { $pageContent=fread(fopen('http://www.yoururl.com/'.base64_encode($i)); } and now I have access to every single URL in your database.

Answer (score 173):

TinyURL doesn't hash anything, it uses Base 36 integers (or even base 62, using lower and uppercase letters) to indicate which record to visit.

Base 36 to Integer:

```
intval($str, 36);
```

Integer to Base 36:

```
base_convert($val, 10, 36);
```

So then, instead of redirecting to a route like `/url/1234` it becomes `/url/ax` instead.  This gives you a whole lot more use than a hash will, as there will be no collisions.  With this you can easily check if a url exists and return the proper, existing, ID in base 36 without the user knowing that it was already in the database.

Don't hash, use other bases for this kind of thing.  (It's faster and can be made collision-proof.)

Comment: hi @RobertK, how would the PHP look for converting 6 digit strings that include both numbers and letters?

Comment: @timpeterson, simply call intval and pass in the given base (see my first code block).

Comment: @RobertK, but `intval()` turns everything into a number. I guess maybe I'm confused on how `intval()` connects with the other steps required to do the redirect like the role of the database.

Comment: @timpeterson, that's because the string represents the ID of the database record. So you select the record based on the passed ID.

Comment: @RobertK, the one problem I'm seeing with `intval()` is if your `$str` has slashes(/) or dashes(-) in it. I realized that `on/stuff`, `on-stuff`, and `on` all returned the number `887`. Do you have a solution in mind to work with URLs with slashes and dashes in them?

Comment: @timpeterson Try [base64_decode](http://php.net/base64_decode) and you should be good to go. Base 36 will only contain 0-9 and a-z; base 62 would contain 0-9 and a-z and A-Z.

Comment: Please note that the result of `intval` will be the maximum signed integer value if the input is very long.

Comment: This is still one-way, tho, right?

Comment: @OlleHärstedt No it's not. Base conversion is reversible. If you want something truly random, this isn't it.

Comment: Also if you're worried about continuity too much which is really easy to guess, you could add a random starting number and increase by a very large prime every time and modulo all this by 2^32 or 2^64 depending on column size

While very easy to reverse engineer and shouldn't be considered security, after a few generated ids it will throw off some script kiddies and can help hidding the numbers of rows in your table

Answer (score 92):

I wrote a tiny lib to generate obfuscated hashes from integers.

[https://github.com/KevBurnsJr/pseudocrypt](http://web.archive.org/web/20130727034425/http://blog.kevburnsjr.com/php-unique-hash)

```
$ids = range(1,10);
foreach($ids as $id) {
  echo PseudoCrypt::unhash($id) . "\n";
}
```

```
m8z2p
8hy5e
uqx83
gzwas
38vdh
phug6
bqtiv
xzslk
k8ro9
6hqqy
```

7/14/2015: Adding the actual code below, since it has become difficult to find:

```
<?php
/**
 * PseudoCrypt by KevBurns (http://blog.kevburnsjr.com/php-unique-hash)
 * Reference/source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1464155/933782
 * 
 * I want a short alphanumeric hash that’s unique and who’s sequence is difficult to deduce. 
 * I could run it out to md5 and trim the first n chars but that’s not going to be very unique. 
 * Storing a truncated checksum in a unique field means that the frequency of collisions will increase 
 * geometrically as the number of unique keys for a base 62 encoded integer approaches 62^n. 
 * I’d rather do it right than code myself a timebomb. So I came up with this.
 * 
 * Sample Code:
 * 
 * echo "<pre>";
 * foreach(range(1, 10) as $n) {
 *     echo $n." - ";
 *     $hash = PseudoCrypt::hash($n, 6);
 *     echo $hash." - ";
 *     echo PseudoCrypt::unhash($hash)."<br/>";
 * }
 * 
 * Sample Results:
 * 1 - cJinsP - 1
 * 2 - EdRbko - 2
 * 3 - qxAPdD - 3
 * 4 - TGtDVc - 4
 * 5 - 5ac1O1 - 5
 * 6 - huKpGQ - 6
 * 7 - KE3d8p - 7
 * 8 - wXmR1E - 8
 * 9 - YrVEtd - 9
 * 10 - BBE2m2 - 10
 */
 
class PseudoCrypt {
 
    /* Key: Next prime greater than 62 ^ n / 1.618033988749894848 */
    /* Value: modular multiplicative inverse */
    private static $golden_primes = array(
        '1'                  => '1',
        '41'                 => '59',
        '2377'               => '1677',
        '147299'             => '187507',
        '9132313'            => '5952585',
        '566201239'          => '643566407',
        '35104476161'        => '22071637057',
        '2176477521929'      => '294289236153',
        '134941606358731'    => '88879354792675',
        '8366379594239857'   => '7275288500431249',
        '518715534842869223' => '280042546585394647'
    );
 
    /* Ascii :                    0  9,         A  Z,         a  z     */
    /* $chars = array_merge(range(48,57), range(65,90), range(97,122)) */
    private static $chars62 = array(
        0=>48,1=>49,2=>50,3=>51,4=>52,5=>53,6=>54,7=>55,8=>56,9=>57,10=>65,
        11=>66,12=>67,13=>68,14=>69,15=>70,16=>71,17=>72,18=>73,19=>74,20=>75,
        21=>76,22=>77,23=>78,24=>79,25=>80,26=>81,27=>82,28=>83,29=>84,30=>85,
        31=>86,32=>87,33=>88,34=>89,35=>90,36=>97,37=>98,38=>99,39=>100,40=>101,
        41=>102,42=>103,43=>104,44=>105,45=>106,46=>107,47=>108,48=>109,49=>110,
        50=>111,51=>112,52=>113,53=>114,54=>115,55=>116,56=>117,57=>118,58=>119,
        59=>120,60=>121,61=>122
    );
 
    public static function base62($int) {
        $key = "";
        while(bccomp($int, 0) > 0) {
            $mod = bcmod($int, 62);
            $key .= chr(self::$chars62[$mod]);
            $int = bcdiv($int, 62);
        }
        return strrev($key);
    }
 
    public static function hash($num, $len = 5) {
        $ceil = bcpow(62, $len);
        $primes = array_keys(self::$golden_primes);
        $prime = $primes[$len];
        $dec = bcmod(bcmul($num, $prime), $ceil);
        $hash = self::base62($dec);
        return str_pad($hash, $len, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
 
    public static function unbase62($key) {
        $int = 0;
        foreach(str_split(strrev($key)) as $i => $char) {
            $dec = array_search(ord($char), self::$chars62);
            $int = bcadd(bcmul($dec, bcpow(62, $i)), $int);
        }
        return $int;
    }
 
    public static function unhash($hash) {
        $len = strlen($hash);
        $ceil = bcpow(62, $len);
        $mmiprimes = array_values(self::$golden_primes);
        $mmi = $mmiprimes[$len];
        $num = self::unbase62($hash);
        $dec = bcmod(bcmul($num, $mmi), $ceil);
        return $dec;
    }
 
}
```

Comment: this has a very intelligent design =D  golden primes = world.rock()

Comment: I know I am commenting on an older post. I thought I would mention that KevBurnsJr code does work well. However, I recently just switched from a Windows 2003 32 bit server to a Windows 2008 R2 x64 server and I am finding that I am duplicating the unique hash's. I am now having to find an alternative method of creating confirmation codes.

Comment: The post has been updated to use bcmath with the help of some commenters so it should be solid now. Someone also found a way to make it reversible which is totally dope.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20130727034425/http://blog.kevburnsjr.com/php-unique-hash it seem website is down so here is the copy of that link ;)

Comment: ya my webserver got, uh, unplugged.

Comment: You ought to get your site back up, or post the php version of this under https://github.com/KevBurnsJr/pseudocrypt - what a great little lib! Didn't want to use a giant "system" like YOURLS or PHURL, just a nice lib to create shortlinks and this is it. Thanks

Comment: Its missing again. After some detective work, I was able to resurrect it here: https://gist.github.com/ethanpil/94455f8de76671aa9024

Comment: Anyone know how the modular multiplicative inverse of 2377 is 1677? I get 3 as value.

Comment: Found the solution to calculate modular multiplicative inverse in this reddit link:  http://www.reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/comments/1gztrp/question_calculate_modular_multiplicative_inverse/capnosi

Comment: Anyone understand why @KevBurnsJr uses the next prime > 62^n / golden ratio?  Why not just choose the next prime > 62^n?  I understand why choosing a small prime might be problematic but why not just any arbitrary large prime?

Comment: I'm loving this little micro library thanks @KevBurnsJr

Comment: Is there a way to salt generated hashes with a seed? Because in this state, the intended use of sequential codes that are "difficult to deduce" isn't really given.

Comment: very clever implementation!

Comment: @j4k3 if you want to randomly "salt" the results, then shuffle the $chars62 array from elements 1 to 61, and make your own unique number->hash bijection. **BUT MAKE SURE YOU KEEP THE FIRST 0=>42 OF THE ARRAY INTACT**. otherwise every hash that starts with 0 will give you bad results at unhashing

Comment: Is this older post still up-to-date? And is it really collision free for integers up to BIGINT_MAX?

Answer (score 24):

Shortest hash is 32 character length, how ever you can use first 8 characters of md5 hash

```
echo substr(md5('http://www.google.com'), 0, 8);
```

**Update**: here is another class found [here](http://snook.ca/archives/php/url-shortener) written by [Travell Perkins](http://twitter.com/tlperkins) which takes record number and create short hash for it. 14 digits number produce 8 digit string. By the date you reach this number you become more popular than tinyurl ;)

```
class BaseIntEncoder {

    //const $codeset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    //readable character set excluded (0,O,1,l)
    const codeset = "23456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    static function encode($n){
        $base = strlen(self::codeset);
        $converted = '';

        while ($n > 0) {
            $converted = substr(self::codeset, bcmod($n,$base), 1) . $converted;
            $n = self::bcFloor(bcdiv($n, $base));
        }

        return $converted ;
    }

    static function decode($code){
        $base = strlen(self::codeset);
        $c = '0';
        for ($i = strlen($code); $i; $i--) {
            $c = bcadd($c,bcmul(strpos(self::codeset, substr($code, (-1 * ( $i - strlen($code) )),1))
                    ,bcpow($base,$i-1)));
        }

        return bcmul($c, 1, 0);
    }

    static private function bcFloor($x)
    {
        return bcmul($x, '1', 0);
    }

    static private function bcCeil($x)
    {
        $floor = bcFloor($x);
        return bcadd($floor, ceil(bcsub($x, $floor)));
    }

    static private function bcRound($x)
    {
        $floor = bcFloor($x);
        return bcadd($floor, round(bcsub($x, $floor)));
    }
}
```

here is example how to use it:

```
BaseIntEncoder::encode('1122344523');//result:3IcjVE
BaseIntEncoder::decode('3IcjVE');//result:1122344523
```

Comment: Using the first 8 charactors of md5 there is probably a reasonable chance of two URLs having the same hash

Comment: Yes such collision might occur, but chance is very little for random string it is about one to 4 billions, how ever if you want to have 100% unique hash which you can use as reference to database record use included class.

Comment: want to mention that `const codeset` may be in any arbitrary order, just to obfuscate++

Answer (score 18):

For a short [hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php), *url friendly*, in the view of disallowing possible duplicate contents, we can use `hash()` and especially the [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) or [Adler-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32) type, since they are made exactly for that:

> **Cyclic Redundancy Check**
>
> A cyclic redundancy check (CRC) is an error-detecting code commonly
> used in digital networks and storage devices to detect accidental
> changes to raw data. Blocks of data entering these systems get a short
> check value attached, based on the remainder of a polynomial division
> of their contents. On retrieval, the calculation is repeated and, in
> the event the check values do not match, corrective action can be
> taken
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

> **Adler-32** is a checksum algorithm (...), compared to a
> Cyclic Redundancy Check of the same length, it trades reliability for
> speed (preferring the latter)
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32

```
echo hash("crc32", "Content of article...");
// Output fd3e7c6e
echo hash("adler32", "Content of article...");
// Output 55df075f
```

[[Youtube] How do CRCs work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izG7qT0EpBw)

Answer (score 2):

Best Answer Yet: [Smallest Unique "Hash Like" String Given Unique Database ID - PHP Solution, No Third Party Libraries Required.](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/converter.html)

Here's the code:

```
<?php
/*
THE FOLLOWING CODE WILL PRINT:
A database_id value of 200 maps to 5K
A database_id value of 1 maps to 1
A database_id value of 1987645 maps to 16LOD
*/
$database_id = 200;
$base36value = dec2string($database_id, 36);
echo "A database_id value of $database_id maps to $base36value\n";
$database_id = 1;
$base36value = dec2string($database_id, 36);
echo "A database_id value of $database_id maps to $base36value\n";
$database_id = 1987645;
$base36value = dec2string($database_id, 36);
echo "A database_id value of $database_id maps to $base36value\n";

// HERE'S THE FUNCTION THAT DOES THE HEAVY LIFTING...
function dec2string ($decimal, $base)
// convert a decimal number into a string using $base
{
    //DebugBreak();
   global $error;
   $string = null;

   $base = (int)$base;
   if ($base < 2 | $base > 36 | $base == 10) {
      echo 'BASE must be in the range 2-9 or 11-36';
      exit;
   } // if

   // maximum character string is 36 characters
   $charset = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

   // strip off excess characters (anything beyond $base)
   $charset = substr($charset, 0, $base);

   if (!ereg('(^[0-9]{1,50}$)', trim($decimal))) {
      $error['dec_input'] = 'Value must be a positive integer with < 50 digits';
      return false;
   } // if

   do {
      // get remainder after dividing by BASE
      $remainder = bcmod($decimal, $base);

      $char      = substr($charset, $remainder, 1);   // get CHAR from array
      $string    = "$char$string";                    // prepend to output

      //$decimal   = ($decimal - $remainder) / $base;
      $decimal   = bcdiv(bcsub($decimal, $remainder), $base);

   } while ($decimal > 0);

   return $string;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote some kind of an algorithm.

It's

1. simpler to understand, tune and change
2. uses only symbols you allow (so it can be case sensitive easily)
3. also unique
4. case insensitive from a box
5. only for positive int (for IDs)

```
<?php

class PseudoCrypt1
{
    private static $keychars = 'CZPXD5H2FIWB81KE76JY93V4ORLAMT0QSUNG'; // Dictionary of allowed unique symbols, shuffle it for yourself or remove unwanted chars (don't forget to call testParameters after changing)
    private static $divider = 19; // Tune divider for yourself (don't forget to call testParameters after changing)
    private static $biasDivider = 14; // Tune bias divider for yourself (don't forget to call testParameters after changing)
    private static $noise = 53; // Any positive number

    public static function testParameters()
    {
        if (strlen(static::$keychars) < static::$divider + static::$biasDivider - 1) {
            throw new Exception('Check your divider and biasDivider. It must be less than keychars length');
        }
    }

    public static function encode(int $i): string
    {
        if ($i < 0) {
            throw new Exception('Expected positive integer');
        }

        $keychars = static::$keychars;
        $i = $i + static::$noise; // add noise to a number
        $bias = $i % static::$biasDivider;

        $res = '';

        while ($i > 0) {
            $div = $i % static::$divider;
            $i = intdiv($i, static::$divider);
            $res .= $keychars[$div + $bias];
        }

        // Current version of an algorithm is one of these chars (if in the future you will need to identify a version)
        // Remember this chars on migrating to a new algorithm/parameters
        $res .= str_shuffle('LPTKEZG')[0];
        $res .= $keychars[$bias]; // Encoded bias

        return $res;
    }

    public static function decode($code)
    {
        $keychars = static::$keychars;
        $biasC = substr($code, -1);
        $bias = strpos($keychars, $biasC);
        $code = substr($code, 0, -2);
        $code = str_split(strrev($code));

        $val = 0;

        foreach ($code as $c) {
            $val *= static::$divider;
            $val += strpos($keychars, $c) - $bias;
        }

        return $val - static::$noise;
    }
}
```

Output

```
36926 -> 7IWFZX
927331 -> F4WIKP2
9021324 -> AT66R7P1
```

You can test it with this little test (it doesn't include test for uniqueness, but algorithm is unique):

```
PseudoCrypt1::testParameters();

for ($i = 4000000; $i < 9500000; $i++) {
    $hash = PseudoCrypt1::encode($i);
    echo $i.':'.strlen($hash).':'.$hash.PHP_EOL;
    if ($i != PseudoCrypt1::decode($hash)) {
        echo 'FAIL:'.$i.PHP_EOL;
        die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the best solution to have "random" hash is to generate a list of random hash, put it on Mysql with an unique INDEX (you can write a simple UDF to insert 100 000 rows in 1 seconde).

I think a structure like this ID|HASH|STATUS|URL|VIEWS|......

Where status indicates if this Hash is free or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was making a url shortner. In my case I used the "id" of database to create every time a unique short url.

What I did is, first -

Insert Data like "Original url" and "creation date"  in db leaving the "short url" empty in db. 
Then get the "id" from there and pass in the function below.

```
<?php
    function genUniqueCode($id){
    $id = $id + 100000000000;
    return base_convert($id, 10, 36);
}

//Get Unique Code using ID
/*
id Below is retrived from Database after Inserting Original URL.
*/



$data['id'] =10;
$uniqueCode = genUniqueCode($data['id']);

   // Generating the URL
$protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],0,5))=='https'?'https':'http';
echo "<a href='{$protocol}://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/{$uniqueCode}'>{$protocol}://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/{$uniqueCode}</a>";

?>
```

And then UPDATE value of Short Url Code in Database.

Here I'm using "id" to create short code. Since ID can't be same for multi entries. It's unique hence the Unique Code or Url will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, perhaps we can use [MurmurHash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) ?

```
function hash_murmur3($string)
{
    $string = array_values(unpack('C*', $string));
    $klen = count($string);
    $h1 = 0;
    $remainder = 0;
    $i = 0;

    for ($bytes = $klen - ($remainder = $klen & 3); $i < $bytes;) {
        $k1 = $string[$i] | ($string[++$i] << 8) | ($string[++$i] << 16) | ($string[++$i] << 24);
        ++$i;
        $k1 = (((($k1 & 0xffff) * 0xcc9e2d51) + (((((($k1 >= 0) ? ($k1 >> 16) : (($k1 & 0x7fffffff) >> 16) | 0x8000)) * 0xcc9e2d51) & 0xffff) << 16))) & 0xffffffff;
        $k1 = $k1 << 15 | (($k1 >= 0) ? ($k1 >> 17) : (($k1 & 0x7fffffff) >> 17) | 0x4000);
        $k1 = (((($k1 & 0xffff) * 0x1b873593) + (((((($k1 >= 0) ? ($k1 >> 16) : (($k1 & 0x7fffffff) >> 16) | 0x8000)) * 0x1b873593) & 0xffff) << 16))) & 0xffffffff;
        $h1 ^= $k1;
        $h1 = $h1 << 13 | (($h1 >= 0) ? ($h1 >> 19) : (($h1 & 0x7fffffff) >> 19) | 0x1000);
        $h1b = (((($h1 & 0xffff) * 5) + (((((($h1 >= 0) ? ($h1 >> 16) : (($h1 & 0x7fffffff) >> 16) | 0x8000)) * 5) & 0xffff) << 16))) & 0xffffffff;
        $h1 = ((($h1b & 0xffff) + 0x6b64) + (((((($h1b >= 0) ? ($h1b >> 16) : (($h1b & 0x7fffffff) >> 16) | 0x8000)) + 0xe654) & 0xffff) << 16));
    }

    $k1 = 0;

    switch ($remainder) {
        case 3:
            $k1 ^= $string[$i + 2] << 16;

        case 2:
            $k1 ^= $string[$i + 1] << 8;

        case 1:
            $k1 ^= $string[$i];
            $k1 = ((($k1 & 0xffff) * 0xcc9e2d51) + (((((($k1 >= 0) ? ($k1 >> 16) : (($k1 & 0x7fffffff) >> 16) | 0x8000)) * 0xcc9e2d51) & 0xffff) << 16)) & 0xffffffff;
            $k1 = $k1 << 15 | (($k1 >= 0) ? ($k1 >> 17) : (($k1 & 0x7fffffff) >> 17) | 0x4000);
            $k1 = ((($k1 & 0xffff) * 0x1b873593) + (((((($k1 >= 0) ? ($k1 >> 16) : (($k1 & 0x7fffffff) >> 16) | 0x8000)) * 0x1b873593) & 0xffff) << 16)) & 0xffffffff;
            $h1 ^= $k1;
    }

    $h1 ^= $klen;
    $h1 ^= (($h1 >= 0) ? ($h1 >> 16) : (($h1 & 0x7fffffff) >> 16) | 0x8000);
    $h1 = ((($h1 & 0xffff) * 0x85ebca6b) + (((((($h1 >= 0) ? ($h1 >> 16) : (($h1 & 0x7fffffff) >> 16) | 0x8000)) * 0x85ebca6b) & 0xffff) << 16)) & 0xffffffff;
    $h1 ^= (($h1 >= 0) ? ($h1 >> 13) : (($h1 & 0x7fffffff) >> 13) | 0x40000);
    $h1 = (((($h1 & 0xffff) * 0xc2b2ae35) + (((((($h1 >= 0) ? ($h1 >> 16) : (($h1 & 0x7fffffff) >> 16) | 0x8000)) * 0xc2b2ae35) & 0xffff) << 16))) & 0xffffffff;
    $h1 ^= (($h1 >= 0) ? ($h1 >> 16) : (($h1 & 0x7fffffff) >> 16) | 0x8000);

    return base_convert(sprintf("%u\n", $h1), 10, 32);
}
```

Usage example:

```
echo hash_murmur3('foo'); // prints '3rabh10'
```