# How to generate a hash string with some special rules in PHP?

Tags: php, hash, cryptographic-hash-function

I'm working on a project where I need to use some hash function to make a hash string. This hash string should be unique consists of 6 to 13 characters (fixed length).

I use a database to store data, so for each record, I have a unique ID. I want to use this unique ID to make a hash string ( to achieve uniqueness of resulted hash string).

I need this hash string to consists of only valid characters ( 0-9 a-z A-Z).

Which hash function should I use to achieve this goal? How can I generate such hash strings?

*Added Later: I want to generate this string and pass it to user, so he can come back later to edit the entry. any other idea is acceptable.*

Comment: Does it need to be a hash? What about generating a string with characters randomly drawn?

Comment: If you want the output to be a unique value, don't use a hash. By definition, hashes map a large set onto a smaller set and there are guaranteed to be collisions. However, you might be lucky enough not to find two items with collisions for many, many years

Comment: @Felix : how to generate random strings with no collision?
@Gareth: Having exact uniqueness is not possible you know, but making the probability of collision as low as possible is my mean by uniqueness.

Comment: @Morteza M.: Well you can generate a string and try to insert the record into the DB (assuming the column has a UNIQUE constraint) and if it fails, generate a new one. Most of the time, you won't generate an already existing string.

Comment: The ID already is unique, so why not use it?

Comment: @phant0m, I can't use just ID, because someone can enter a random ID and edit the entry.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Your idea is good. I think about it:) thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use crypt:

```
$hash = crypt("somevaluetohash", $uniqueid);
```

The unique id is a salt so you can generate different values depending on the id. So if one user had a password of "somevaluetohash" and another user had the same, the ending hash wouldn't be the same.

Comment: I planned to use it, but it generates some special characters like dot,slash and so on. I want the string to contains only alphanumeric characters.

Comment: You can always make a filter for this. Or you could make a hash with
    $hash = md5("somevaluetohash".$uniqueid);

Comment: your idea is good. but can I somehow reduce the length of generated code to 6 or 13 ( not using a simple crop ).

Comment: Maybe check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959957/php-short-hash ? If you cant find any other method of hashing which has a 6 to 13 length, just use the same method: "somevaluetohash".$uniqueid

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $id;
  $hash_full = md5($id); //hash('sha256', $id);
  $hash_cropped = substr($hash_full, 0, 6);
?>
```

Use [hash()](http://ch.php.net/manual/de/function.hash.php) for other hashing algorithms.

But what do you need this hashes for? To me, it doesn't make a lot of sense to generate a hash from the ID, couldn't you just use the ID instead?

Comment: You know, I want to pass this string to user, as a password so he can edit the entry later. I don't cropping a hash string put it in danger of more collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Does it really need to be a cryptographic checksum? Or is a simpler checksum suitable? Is the database-provided primary key itself not suitable?

You've got lots of options, from the simplest [crc32](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) to most-advanced [sha512](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php).

But if you're doing this for some specific application (such as [filesystem hashing](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext3/hash.c), or [finding nearby objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_hashing) using some metrics), then you're going to have to specify more of your problem.