# How to use a short unique hash (with only 4-6 chars) from urls

Tags: php, url, hash, unique

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php short hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959957/php-short-hash)

I need to generate a short hash.  The shortest possible from urls say under 6 characters.

I need them to be unique just for the same domain, so a hash from

`www.example.com/category/sth/blablabla`   must be different than one from 
`www.example.com/category2/sth/blabla` but not from:
`www.example2.com/category/sth/blablabla`

Would using `md5($url)` and then picking some 5 characters out of that result (for example the first, last, middle and 2 other characters) give and unique id?

Would this abbreviated hash be unique as well?

Comment: If the path name is unbounded in your problem, then there cannot be any bounded unique hash, simply by counting (colourfully called the "pidgeon-hole principle").

Comment: If you're trying to minimize the length of the hash (in characters, or bytes?), you must maximize the uniqueness per character. Can you use UTF-8/unicode characters?

Answer (score 1):

A hash is not unique by definition. It's mathematically impossible to get a unique hash for something longer than the hash, unless it does not vary fully, which is the case for URLs but you cannot exploit it generally. Alternatively, you could use a simple incrementing ID, but that won't allow you to recognize matching URLs.

Either use a really long hash (at least 10 characters, ideally using upper and lower case letters), or accept collisions and handle them appropriately. Which is how actual [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) work.

Comment: "you could use a simple incrementing ID, but that won't allow you to recognize matching URLs", yeah I need to match urls so I can't use this method. I think short tags and checking for collision could be the solution

Answer (score 1):

For low probability of collisions you can use universal hashing techniques. For example, choose a prime number P. Then for each character of the URL choose a random in the interval [0, P). Compute the hash of the URL as SUM(a[i]*c[i]) mod P, where c[i] is a character in the original URL. Then take the string containing the digits of the obtained integer as the hash.

Read more in this paper: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451/lectures/lect0929.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a small change in a URL will change pretty much every character in a good hash. MD5 or SHA1 is probably fine for this. Hence, take the first X characters - and you won't get any improvement by choosing the last X characters, or the first/last/middle. They're all good!

Obviously the more characters you put in your partial hash, the less likely you are to get collisions.

Comment: (If www.example.com is the same as www.example2.com, then search-and-replace the latter to the former before hashing.)

Answer (score -1):

I would try using `crc32($url)`; it will give an integer usually 10-11 digits-long, could be a negative value, but still it will be shorter than 32 chars for md5.

The only problem is that crc32 is not 100% unique, but it's very unlikely that two different URLs will end up with the same checksum (but still there is a possibility).

Comment: The probability is greater than 50% if you have more than 2^16 URLs, which is not all that many.