Determine CRC algorithm from recorded data
I have the following recorded command packets, 32 byte each:
3da89fc200180010000000000000000024100001240400010000000000000000 
d427eb5a00180010000000000000000024100001240300010000000000000000 
984870ff00180010000000000000000024100001240200010000000000000000 
4ab8076100180010000000000000000024100001240100010000000000000000 
06d79cc400180010000000000000000024100001240000010000000000000000 

The first 4 bytes are supposed to be a "Ethernet CRC-32" checksum of the remaining 28 bytes. I want to create custom commands, so I need to figure out how to calculate the CRC.
I tried any variation of CRC32 that I can think of and even tried "reveng -w 32 -c " on the data given above, hoping to find the right CRC settings. No luck. I suspect there is some weird data reordering happening before and maybe even after the CRC calculation.
How can I approach this problem? Is there an automated way to try different permutations of the data?

It's possible that these CRC are made from a different system architecture, thus btw PHP has 3 versions of CRC built-in: crc32, crc32b, crc32c. Maybe have a test, to help to sort that out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62332485/2494754

Some hints: use -s for reveng to search; reveng is expecting the CRC to be at the end of the message, so move it for feeding reveng; the CRC may be byte-swapped, so also try reversing the four bytes.

Can you provide a link to the documentation you are quoting?

The data shown in the question is the "CONTINUOUS_IMAGE_DOWNLOAD_CMD" command per https://www.ti.com/de/lit/pdf/swru599 §4.6.2.5.3. It is recorded from a working reference implementation that doesn't seem to quite match the documentation.

The checksum appears to be generated by a hardware CRC module: https://www.ti.com/de/lit/pdf/swru599 §22.5

You may want to verify the transcription of your examples.

Thanks Mark for the great input.
I spent some more time looking into the rest of the message (excluding the CRC) and found that the data is ordered differently from what I expected. It is byte-swapped. I have seen that with other TI SPI code: they create the command packets as an array of uint32_t in little endian order, but have the SPI module configured for 16-bit transfers with MSB first.
Value: 0x00012410

Memory Address   0     1    2    3
Memory Bytes     0x10  0x24 0x01 0x00
Memory Words     0x2410     0x0001

SPI Bytes        0x24 0x10 0x00 0x01

So I byte-swapped the recorded packets to recreate the memory layout that was used to calculate the CRC. To make it work with reveng, I also moved the CRC to the end of the message as recommended by Mark.
Reordered data:
18001000000000000000000010240100042401000000000000000000a83dc29f
1800100000000000000000001024010003240100000000000000000027d45aeb
180010000000000000000000102401000224010000000000000000004898ff70
18001000000000000000000010240100012401000000000000000000b84a6107
18001000000000000000000010240100002401000000000000000000d706c49c
Now, reveng confirms that it's a pretty normal CRC:
~/reveng-3.0.6/reveng -w 32 -s 18001000000000000000000010240100042401000000000000000000a83dc29f 1800100000000000000000001024010003240100000000000000000027d45aeb 180010000000000000000000102401000224010000000000000000004898ff70 18001000000000000000000010240100012401000000000000000000b84a6107 18001000000000000000000010240100002401000000000000000000d706c49c
width=32  poly=0x04c11db7  init=0xffffffff  refin=true  refout=true  xorout=0xffffffff  check=0xcbf43926  residue=0xdebb20e3  name="CRC-32/ISO-HDLC"

Aha! Now my brute-force program finds it as well.

With so little variation among the messages (only three bits change), what I can say after an initial analysis that they are not inconsistent with those bytes being a CRC. That conclusion comes from the only dependent message, which has a 3 in the varying hexadecimal digit. It depends on the messages with 0, 1, and 2 at that position. If I take the CRCs for those message and exclusive-or them together, I get the CRC for the message with 3. 0x06d79cc4 ^ 0x4ab80761 ^ 0x984870ff == 0xd427eb5a.
So the data provided, such as it is, is consistent with a linear function over GF(2), which a CRC is one of. I can use this approach to compute that function for the other three possible values for those three bits.
Detailing the math for this a bit: if I exclusive-or one of the messages, including the CRC, with all of the remaining ones, I now have examples of CRC's with a zero initial value and zero final exclusive-or. Those get cancelled out. So I choose the message with a 0 in the varying position for that. I now have messages that are all zeros, except for a 1, 2, 3, or 4 digit. If I exclusive-or the new messages with 1 and 2, I get a message with a 3 in that position. You will find that it matches the new message (with CRC) with a 3 in that position. The fact that they match shows that the set is not inconsistent with the first four bytes being a linear function over GF(2) of the remaining bytes.
However, after a brute-force search, I found that the provided data is not consistent with any 32-bit CRC! If I assume that the portion that the CRC is computed over is some number of contiguous bytes of the provided messages, of course including the byte that varies, and that the CRC provided is in either little or big-endian order, then neither a forward nor a reverse CRC using any 32-bit polynomial will work.
